# AngularJS Object from JSON String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an Angular object that looks something like this (menuItems contain more data but thats not the point):

```
$scope.data = {
   title:'Title',
   place:'Somewhere'
   menuItems: [{
        title: "This is a Title",
        name: "John"},
                {
        title: "Another Title",
        name: "Frank"} ]
};
```

I create this $scope.data with default values. They are always the same. This data is used to fill an html page using ng-model. As well as a ng-repeat call to display all the menuItems.

```
<input class="text form-control" ng-model="data.title"></div>
<div ng-repeat="item in data.menuItems">
   <input class="text form-control" ng-model="item.name"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

I then successfully exported the data object to a JSON string like so:

```
$scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.data, false);
```

Which yield a JSON string similar to this one:

```
{"menuItems":[{"title":"This is a title","name":"John"},{"title":"Another Title","name":"Frank"}],"title":"Title", "place":"Somewhere"}
```

What I want to do now is to load this JSON string and overwrite the $scope.data object (to provide means to modify an existing JSON string).

I load the string like so:

```
var json = JSON.stringify("{"menuItems":[{"title":"This is a title","name":"John"},{"title":"Another Title","name":"Frank"}],"title":"Title", "place":"Somewhere"}");
$scope.data = JSON.parse(json);
```

But no data is updated and all the divs created within the ng-repeat disappear.

I cannot change the structure of the JSON as it is used this way in another application. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: yes. no errors. the stringified json string appears to be correct as well

Comment: `"{"menuItems":[{"title":"This is a title","name":"John"},{"title":"Another Title","name":"Frank"}],"title":"Title", "place":"Somewhere"}")` Are you sure this is valid JSON? It looks like inner quotes are not escaped / the outer quotes are not different from the inner ones.

Comment: just use this line - $scope.data = JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify($scope.data));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `$scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.data, false);` the way to do the opposite in angular would be `angular.fromJson($scope.json)`.

Also make sure that your JSON is valid. ie `"{"menuItems":[{"title":"This is a title","name":"John"},{"title":"Another Title","name":"Frank"}],"title":"Title", "place":"Somewhere"}")` looks like your inner quotes are not escaped, or you don't use single quotes as the outer quotes.

Comment: This should be under comments section. not Answers

Comment: Thanks, I've rephrased it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape quotes:

```
var json = JSON.parse("{\"menuItems\":[{\"title\":\"This is a title\",\"name\":\"John\"},{\"title\":\"Another Title\",\"name\":\"Frank\"}],\"title\":\"Title\", \"place\":\"Somewhere\"}");
```

Also you are stringifying string! `JSON.stringify` expects object and returns JSON string.